# csv to xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, csv

I have a c# code in which
I'm having a csv file containing customer data as follows:

```
ClientNumber1,Name1, BenefitCode1, EffectiveDt1 
ClientNumber1,Name1, BenefitCode2, EffectiveDt2 
ClientNumber2,Name2, BenefitCode3, EffectiveDt3
```

Now in this case I want the output XML to have mutliple tags for `Benefit` within same customer (eg, the first two rows in my csv have same customer but two different benefits)

My output xml should be like

```
<Member>
<Num>ClientNumber1<Num>
<Nm>Name1</Nm>
 <Benefit>
  <Bc>BenefitCode1</Bc>
  <Dt>EffectiveDt1</Dt>
 </Benefit>
 <Benefit>
  <Bc>BenefitCode2</Bc>
  <Dt>EffectiveDt2</Dt>
 </Benefit>
</Member>
<Member>
<Num>ClientNumber1<Num>
<Nm>Name2</Nm>
 <Benefit>
   <Bc>BenefitCode3</Bc>
   <Dt>EffectiveDt3</Dt>
 </Benefit>
</Member>
```

So basically, while I performing the LINQ I should also be able to check it with previous `ClientNum` and in case I have the same num, the benefit data should be added within the same `Member` tag.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems like you need deserialize csv strings to data structure, and then serialize it to xml

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us what have your tried so far and what specific problem you have, as SO is not 'write me some code' portal.

Comment: Well currently I've tried the following code and this works but I need the Benefit data to be aggregated into single tag.<br>  String[] File1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv");

            String xml = "";

            XElement top = new XElement("Client",

            from items in File1

            let fields = items.Split(',')

            select new XElement("Benefit",

            new XElement("bc", fields[0]),

            new XElement("dt", fields[1])

            )

            );

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\xmlout.xml", xml + top.ToString());

Comment: @user1705851 add this to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split this into two clearly separated steps:

1) Create data representation from file - by creating anonymous types, grouped by client number:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv")
               .Select(line => line.Split(','))
               .Select(parts => new
                {
                    ClientNumber = parts[0].Trim(),
                    Name = parts[1].Trim(),
                    BenefitCode = parts[2].Trim(),
                    EffectiveDate = parts[3].Trim()
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.ClientNumber);
```

2) Save data as XML:

```
var xml = new XDocument(
        new XElement("SomeRoot",
                output.Select(e => new XElement("Member",
                        new XElement("Num", e.Key),
                        new XElement("Name", e.First().Name),
                        e.Select(x => new XElement("Benefit",
                            new XElement("Bc", x.BenefitCode),
                            new XElement("Dt", x.EffectiveDate)))
                    ))
            )
    );
```

Then you can save it to file with `xml.Save(...)`

Comment: I am having some more columns and different data types but this code works. Thanks a lot...!!!